# why open a file has an encoding setting rather than decoding setting?

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, ascii

sorry if my question sounds dumb. I know how different encoding like UTF-8, UTF-16 works, but confuse with some file processing program like Windows's Notepad.

when I save a file, I can see an option "Encoding":
[image]

that sounds reasonable, because we want to encoding the content then save it.

But when I open a file, I still see the encoding option:
[image]

That doesn't make sense to me, becuase now I want to read the file, so decoding should kick it and decode the content so that I can see meaningful content, shouldn't the text of the option box call "Decoding" instead of "Encoding"

Comment: "Encoding" as a noun means *the method with which the file is or should be encoded*. It can be used both ways.

Comment: As @deceze correctly stated you should not think of these words as "Save this file to xyz.txt, encoding it as UTF-8" but "Save this file to xyz.txt, using *the encoding* called UTF-8". If you phrase it like that then the usage in both saving and loading makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @JoachimSauer so let's say the content of the file in binary(one byte) is 00000001, and I save the file with UTF-16, will the file content still be 00000001(one byte) or 0000000000000001(two bytes)?

Comment: @slowjams: I don't see how this comment is reasonably related to the question you posted. Maybe you're making some assumptions that I don't understand. There's also some assumptions in your comment that would need to be addressed, but if you save 1 Unicode codepoint worth of text (roughly "one character") as UTF-16, then the file will be 2 bytes long.